# How to freeze and thaw black eyed peas

Tags: freezing, beans

I'm considering moving from canned black eyed peas to dry black eyed peas since they're cheaper. I'm thinking of batch boiling them and freezing them but I'm not sure if I could eat them straight after thawing without cooking them again. I usually eat black eyed peas cold as a salad/side dish. Would their texture be good after thawing? And what would be the best way to freeze them - after cooking do I just put them in a tupperware? Thank you so much!

Comment: I’ve made batches of black bean soup, put it into freezer bags, and then laid them out on sheet pans to freeze.  That thawed out well, but I don’t know about just freezing beans as an ingredient.

Comment: I do the same as @Joe but with mixed bean chilli and various stews, all starting from dried beans.

Answer (score 5):

Beans freeze very well in my experience.  We cook from dried, place extra in quart containers with some of the bean cooking liquor, and freeze.  Thaw slowly in the refrigerator (that helps protect texture).  Use however you like.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this

Answer (score 2):

If you cook them before freezing, they will still be cooked after freezing, so no need to "cook them again" on that basis.

As for texture, the simplest thing to do is try a small batch and see what *you* think. Freezing does often affect texture somewhat - whether *you* find the change objectionable is going to be up to you.

Freezing will be more rapid and even if you get the beans into a thin layer, such as the freezer bags laid flat on a pan that @Joe uses for soup. If using tupperware or similar containers, try a large flat one with a thin layer and a deeper one and see if that makes any difference in your assessment of the texture. *Usually* faster freezing (thin layer) is percieved to be better, but experimenting might show that for your taste it either matters a lot, or not at all. All it costs is a container of beans, that will still be edible, even if the result tells you not to do it that way again.

Comment: I don’t know if liquid in the container when freezing is also significant… if nothing else, it minimizes the air so would reduce the chance of freezer burn

Comment: Reasonable to try freezing with/without the liquid. With would also be "more similar" to canned beans. My read of the question is that the intent is short term freezing for meal-prep, not freezing a year's worth of beans at once, so freezer burn may not be a large problem, unless a container gets lost for a long time in the freezer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, I'm thinking of trying a small batch yes, but I'm still looking for opinions because I really only like black eyed peas cold in salads so if I don't like the texture of them thawed I will be at a loss on what to do. And yes, I'm planning on short term (3 months max) freezing for easier meal prep.

Comment: If you don't like the frozen/thawed texture, limit the amount you cook to what you will use before it spoils in the refrigerator, unless you want to get into pressure-canning.